# How do I install and use Scrooge

Tags: scala, thrift, thrift-protocol, scrooge

I want to write a Thrift service using Scrooge.

Thrift has almost no documentation and Scrooge has even less.

How do I install Scrooge on an Ubuntu or OSX machine?

Once installed, and I have created a .thrift, how do I use Scrooge to generate server code and client code?

Comment: i found no information on this topic.  http://bit.ly/121mZbB

Comment: are you familiar with sbt ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a giter8 template for you.

1. Install conscript

   > curl https://raw.github.com/n8han/conscript/master/setup.sh | sh
2. Install giter8

   > cs n8han/giter8
3. Get my template

   > g8 MasseGuillaume/scrooge
4. Install sbt (I Like sbt-extra) + add sbt to your $PATH

   > curl https://raw.github.com/paulp/sbt-extras/master/sbt > ~/bin/sbt
5. apply default parameters
6. Start a server on a terminal tab

   > sbt server/run
7. Start a client on another terminal tab when the server has started

   > sbt client/run

Comment: I had to add ~/bin to my $PATH

Comment: at the g8 step i get UnknownHostKey: github.com. RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d
:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.  investigating

Comment: on step 6 I get:  [info] Set current project to api (in build file:/home/ericstob/authordetails/)

[error] Expected ':'

[error] Not a valid key: start (similar: state, target, start-year)

[error] Server/start

Comment: sbt server/run (lower case s) made it work for me.  Thanks!  Marking answer.

Comment: Alternatively, on OSX, you can use `brew install giter8` to avoid installing conscript. You will need to have brew installed. But I would guess that more people have homebrew installed than conscript on OSX.